My WordPress post container starts from Row1 coulmn2
My WordPress post first row and first column goes blank and it starts from second column. In the pictures I selected 4 columns but it starts filling content from second column as screenshot

I expect my post should start from the 1st row 1st column.

This is probably a css issue. Use your browser’s developer tools and you will quickly find out why you see this behaviour.
